# Rearrange numbers in an Array in ascending order and print them in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My program so far creates an array based on a user's declared size.  The program then fills that array with random numbers between 500 and 600 and prints the 4 of those numbers and creates a new line to continue printing them.  Everything works fine up to this point.  At the part where it is suppose to reprint the numbers in ascending order something goes wrong and it reprints only some of the numbers and not in any order. Any help on how to correct this is appreciated.

```
int main(){
            int size;
            int j, i;
        int temp;
        int a=0;
        double sum = 0;


        printf("Enter size of array ");
        scanf("%d", &size);


        int* array;
        array=malloc(size * sizeof(*array));
        int *aPtr = array;

        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
             aPtr[i] =(rand() % 101) + 500;
             printf("%d ", aPtr[i]);
             a++;
             if (a == 4){
            printf("\n");
            a = 0;
            }


      }
        printf("\n\n\nIn ascending order\n");
        for (i = 0; i< size; i++){
             for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(aPtr[i] > aPtr[j]);
                temp=aPtr[i];
                aPtr[i]=aPtr[j];
                    aPtr[j]=temp;
                    }
                printf("%d\n", aPtr[i]);
            }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  I guess your sorting isn't working - why do you need to reimplement it yourself instead of using one of the many already-written options?  Anyway, it sounds like it's time to break out a debugger and step through your code.  You should see what's going wrong in short order.

Comment: I've tried debugging with gdb but my knowledge on how to use it is pretty limited.  What are the already-written options?

Comment: [heapsort(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/heapsort/), [mergesort(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/mergesort/), and [qsort(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/qsort/), to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a result of the < sign, and the if statement not being in its own brackets. The second for loop for printing also helped print array correctly

```
 printf("\n\n\nIn ascending order\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
             for (j = i+1; j < size; j++){
            if(aPtr[i] > aPtr[j]){
                temp=aPtr[i];
                aPtr[i]=aPtr[j];
                    aPtr[j]=temp;
            }
            }
            }
            for (j = 0; j<size; j++)                
            printf("%d\n", aPtr[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the if-test in your sorting loop (reformatted):

```
for (i = 0; i< size; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if(aPtr[i] > aPtr[j]);
        temp=aPtr[i];
        aPtr[i]=aPtr[j];
        aPtr[j]=temp;
    }
    printf("%d\n", aPtr[i]);
}
```

You are swapping every value regardless because you did not put any content in the if-block.  This should fix your code with minimal changes:

```
for (i = 0; i< size; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if(aPtr[i] > aPtr[j]) {
            temp=aPtr[i];
            aPtr[i]=aPtr[j];
            aPtr[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", aPtr[i]);
}
```

Note that with bubble-sort, you only need to search for the *index* of the minimum element and swap *once*.  You are swapping every time which is pretty redundant.  You also do not need to loop from zero in the inner `j` loop, because everything before `i` is already sorted.

```
int minidx;
for (i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    /* Find index of smallest element in the rest of the array */
    minidx = i;
    for (j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
        if(aPtr[j] < aPtr[minidx]) minidx = j;
    }

    /* Swap if necessary */
    if (minidx != i ) {
        temp = aPtr[i];
        aPtr[i] = aPtr[minidx];
        aPtr[minidx] = temp;
    }

    /* The element at i is now sorted */
    printf("%d\n", aPtr[i]);
}
```